# aws s3 sync --delete, does not remove directory manually created from console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

aws s3 sync <> <> --delete works fine but I have a scenario wherein someone created directories using AWS console and put in some files inside those directories using manual upload. So now when I run the **sync** command, those files get removed but the manually created directories still persist.

Is this an expected behavior of the command?

Comment: It looks like you have raised this at [awscli GitHub issues](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/7098). I think that's the best approach. Arguably, this is a bug imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is tracked here - https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2685 . This is a known bug and no direct solution is available yet so we need to create wayarounds according to our condition.